# Cardinality is reported as "1" even though there are 2 unique values stored for the corresponding column

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, cardinality

I am trying to optimize my database by adjusting indices.

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM my_table
```

outputs

```
Table     ...  Key_name    ...   Column_name  ...  Cardinality ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------
my_table  ...  idx_field1  ...    field1      ...      1       ...
```

while

```
SELECT field1 FROM my_table PROCEDURE ANALYSE()\G
```

outputs

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Field_name: my_db.my_table.field1
  Min_value: ow
  Max_value: rt
  Min_length: 2
  Max_length: 2
  Empties_or_zeros: 0
  Nulls: 0
  Avg_value_or_avg_length: 2.0000
  Std: NULL
  Optimal_fieldtype: ENUM('ow','rt') NOT NULL
1 row in set (0.26 sec)
```

i.e., **the reported cardinality (1) is not equal to the number of unique values (2). Why?**

PS. I did perform

```
analyze table my_table
```

before running the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "cardinality" in `SHOW INDEXES` is an approximation.  `ANALYSE()` gets the exact value because it is derived from an exhaustive scan of the table.

The former is used for deciding how to optimize a query.  Generally, a low cardinality (whether 1 or 2) implies that an index on that field is not worth using.

Where are you headed with this question?

Comment: I was considering using `idx_field1` as index, since discarding 50% of the rows (_due to cardinality(2)_) seemed to be an improvement to me. But yeah, I understood that the distribution of those 2 unique values doesn't have to be even, which means I could get 99 'ow's and only 1 'rt', and then I would practically get no improvement at all if searching for 'ow's.

Comment: Now you are getting the picture.  One more note:  when using an index, the executing bounces between the index BTree and the data BTree; this is somewhat costly.  The break-even is at about 20% -- if more than 20% of the rows have a given value, it is faster to ignore the index and simply scan the table.